# Improve Web page Aesthetics in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

I am designing a login page.Currently I just have fieldset in my form.I want to improve the look of it.I am using jsp.Following is the code.

I want to display login in a frame.

```
<s:form action = "LogInAction" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>
    <s:textfield name="username" key="label.username"></s:textfield>
    <s:password name="password" key="label.password"></s:password>
    <s:submit method="execute" key="label.login" align="center" />
  </fieldset>
</s:form>
```

Comment: Code for it is <s:form action = "LogInAction" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend> Login </legend>
<s:textfield name="username" key="label.username"></s:textfield>
<s:password name="password" key="label.password"> </s:password>
<s:submit method="execute" key="label.login" align="center" />
</fieldset>
</s:form>

Comment: please edit the question properly instead of putting the code snippet in the comment. Thanks

Comment: The edited question is not getting saved.:(

Comment: how do you want to improve the look of it? what have you tried to get that? any CSS code you can post here?

Comment: The username and password fields appear to be outside the Login fieldset with the current code which I have posted.I want the fieldset in the center of the page and adjust the size of the Login form.